# node js warning about promise rejections

Tags: node.js

I today run my node js app that i development for months and before it was all excellent..now in console i see this warning errors:

```
(node:19318) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: done is not defined
(node:19318) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:19318) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 2): ReferenceError: done is not defined
(node:19318) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 3): ReferenceError: done is not defined
(node:19318) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 4): ReferenceError: done is not defined
(node:19318) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 5): ReferenceError: done is not defined
(node:19318) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 6): ReferenceError: done is not defined
```

Where can I find what module or function is causing this warning? Because yesterday works all excellent and no code modification is done...where I can search for a problem to fix it? I try to search for Promise in index.js but there is not found...so I think that some npm module is using Promise and how to detect what is it? Does node js have some log text file output that writes in text file description of error what causing it?

Comment: you have a function called "done" but not defied.
try to search in your project for all done(). mostly it should be passed as argument.

Comment: I have this function `if (err) return done(err);` what i need to rewrite it to be correct? Should i put `console.log(err)` or remove it?

Comment: I fixed it using your suggestion...i changed above code to `if (err) return;` and no more warnings and all is working excellent...thanks....Ahmed

Comment: @John it sounds like that fix will just ignore any errors, which doesn't seem like a good solution. It depends on your code on how to fix it _properly_.

Comment: I know...but this error just return mysql error (if sql command is not qood...so when i will publish complete project it is not good to have errors in console..i can return json to client side to get error described but then app will be sql attackers injections easy..this way when program will have problems..i will just do console.log(err) to see what sql is causing error...thanks for reminder.

Comment: have you used try catch block.?